# Negating a method call in an Expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I'm generating a c# Linq expression dynamically as below, which will (in the example below) run string.Contains against the collection values.

```
var dynamicMethod = "Contains";
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (MyClass), "type");
var property = Expression.Property(parameter, "MyProperty");
var constantValue = Expression.Constant("PropertyValue", property.Type);
var method = property.Type.GetMethod(dynamicMethod, new[] {property.Type});
var expression = Expression.Call(property, method, constantValue);
```

For the above code, I'd want something equivalent to !Contains.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about [Expression.Not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299047.aspx)? That would simply be:

```
var condition = Expression.Not (contains_call);
```

Comment: Works great...I was originally trying Expression.Negate() but appears that Expression.Not() is what I was looking for.